# GCM Terms and Conditions

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Does anyone know where can I find the Terms and Conditions regarding what can and can't be sent out through GCM notifications? I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you sign-up to open a Google API account, you get these [terms & conditions](https://developers.google.com/cloud/terms).

When you activate Google Cloud Messaging you get these [terms & conditions](https://cloud.google.com/console/tos?id=googlecloudmessaging) which lead you to these [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/terms/).

I haven't read it all, but I can't see any specifics about what you can and can't send with GCM.

There are, however, some general prohibitions that apply also to GCM :

```
API Prohibitions

When using the APIs, the following prohibitions apply:
    - You will not sublicense an API for use by a third party. Consequently, you will not create an API Client that functions substantially the same as the APIs and offer it for use by third parties.
    - You will not perform an action with the intent of introducing to Google products and services any viruses, worms, defects, Trojan horses, malware or any items of a destructive nature.
    - You will not defame, abuse, harass, stalk or threaten others.
    - You will not interfere with or disrupt the APIs or the servers or networks providing the APIs.
    - You will not promote or facilitate unlawful online gambling or disruptive commercial messages or advertisements.
    - You will not reverse engineer or attempt to extract the source code from any API or any related software, except to the extent that this restriction is expressly prohibited by applicable law.
    - Certain developer credentials are, by their nature, considered confidential. You will not disclose such confidential credentials to any third party except your agent(s) using such information solely on your behalf in accordance with these terms and under a written duty of confidentiality.
    - Our communications to you may contain Google confidential information. If you receive any materials or communications that are clearly confidential or marked confidential, then you will not disclose the Google confidential information to any third party without Google's prior written consent.
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging terms of conditions are here:

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/terms